# Enable/Disable click functions when the pop up appears

Tags: jquery

```
   function unloadPopupBox() {    
        $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
        $(".categoryContent").css({
            "opacity": "1"  
        }); 
        $('.categoryContent').click(function(){return true;});// Not working
        $(".headingA").bind('click');// Not working
        $( ".categoryMenu" ).tabs( { disabled: false } ); //Working
    }    

    function loadPopupBox() {   
        $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
        $(".categoryContent").css({ 
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });  
        $('.categoryContent').click(function(){return false;});//Working
        $(".headingA").unbind('click');  //Working
        $( ".categoryMenu" ).tabs( { disabled: [1, 2, 3] } );  //Working 
    }
```

When I open the PopUp, some specific clicks in the background should be disabled and when the Pop Up is closed, the clicks should be enabled again. But here disabling works whereas enabling those clicks is not working?? What should i do exactly here???

Comment: document.getElementById("input-id").disabled=true || disabled=false should solve ur problem.Every form element has disabled option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Try This Code to make model popup.

```
<h3>JQuery Popup Dialogs</h3>

<input type="button" id="btnShowSimple" value="Simple Dialog" />
<input type="button" id="btnShowModal" value="Modal Dialog" />

<br /><br />       

<div id="output"></div>

<div id="overlay" class="web_dialog_overlay"></div>

<div id="dialog" class="web_dialog">
<table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
     <td class="web_dialog_title">Online Survey</td>
     <td class="web_dialog_title align_right">
        <a href="#" id="btnClose">Close</a>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 15px;">
        <b>Choose your favorite mobile brand? </b>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 15px;">
        <div id="brands">
           <input id="brand1" name="brand" type="radio" checked="checked" value="Nokia" /> Nokia
           <input id="brand2" name="brand" type="radio" value="Sony" /> Sony 
           <input id="brand3" name="brand" type="radio" value="Motorola" /> Motorola
        </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
     </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

**JS Code is**

```
(document).ready(function ()
 {
  $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e)
  {
     ShowDialog(false);
     e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#btnShowModal").click(function (e)
  {
     ShowDialog(true);
     e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#btnClose").click(function (e)
  {
     HideDialog();
     e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e)
  {
     var brand = $("#brands input:radio:checked").val();
     $("#output").html("<b>Your favorite mobile brand: </b>" + brand);
     HideDialog();
     e.preventDefault();
  });
```

});

```
  function ShowDialog(modal)
 {
  $("#overlay").show();
  $("#dialog").fadeIn(300);

  if (modal)
  {
     $("#overlay").unbind("click");
  }
  else
  {
     $("#overlay").click(function (e)
     {
        HideDialog();
     });
  }
```

}

```
 function HideDialog()
 {
  $("#overlay").hide();
  $("#dialog").fadeOut(300);
 }
```

Try That link for Live Demo

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/937kH/)

### Hope It helps you